# Posting the value of a radio button using curl

Tags: php, forms, curl, radio-button

I need to post the value of a radio button using curl but the result of the post keep telling me the radio button is not selected. This is the html code with the radio buttons:

```
<div class="unit"><input type="radio" tabindex="11" value="4" id="atrib_1" name="attr_frete" class="radio_bt"></div>
<label for="atrib_gratis" class="radio_label">Flete 1</label>
<div class="unit"><input type="radio" tabindex="11" value="5" id="atrib_2" name="attr_frete" class="radio_bt"></div>
<label for="atrib_gratis" class="radio_label">Flete 2</label>
```

And this is how I pass the value:

```
'attr_frete='.urlencode(4).
```

What am I missing or doing wrong ? Please help.